Why my react project shows me 'No overload matches this call.' error only in vscode? (not in the prettier)
Here is my simple source code.
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import logo from '../assets/logo.svg';

const LogoContainer = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4%;
  left: calc(50% - 7%);
`;

const LogoImage = styled.img`
  width: 14%;
  height: auto;
`;

const Logo: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <LogoContainer>
      <LogoImage src={logo} alt="Logo" />
    </LogoContainer>
  );
};

export default Logo;

It works well in my browser, and also no error from the prettier side.
But only in vscode, it returns an error for the src and background also.
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: PolymorphicComponentProps<"web", FastOmit<DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>, never>, void, void, {}, {}>): Element', gave the following error.
    Type 'FunctionComponent<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string | undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: FastOmit<DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>, never>): ReactNode', gave the following error.
    Type 'FunctionComponent<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string | undefined; }>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
index.d.ts(3252, 9): The expected type comes from property 'src' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FastOmit<Substitute<FastOmit<DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>, never>, FastOmit<...>>, keyof ExecutionProps> & FastOmit<...> & { ...; }'
index.d.ts(3252, 9): The expected type comes from property 'src' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & FastOmit<DetailedHTMLProps<ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>, never>'

capture-vscode
I'm using airbnb style eslint and prettier, typescript and react. How should I do for this error? Ignore, or some configuration change?
I've tried to change configuration files but I couldn't find any solutions yet

"no error from the prettier side" - well of course, it's a TypeScript error!

@Bergi Thanks for pointing that what I've missed, but if then why my npm is showing no errors when I run..? I also couldn't understand why is there error for src of the img. Maybe because of styled.img doesn't have that option..?

What is import logo from '../assets/logo.svg'; doing? What build chain do you use, what plugins did you install, to be able to import svg files? TypeScript complains that src should be a string, but logo is typed as a function component.

I didn't installed plugins, I declared it in custum.d.ts. They can load it and works fine, but maybe it is against the rule for typescript. Could you recommend me some other ways to load svg files if my way is not recommended?
declare module '*.svg' {
  import * as React from 'react';

  const ReactComponent: React.FunctionComponent<
    React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> & { title?: string }
  >;

  export default ReactComponent;
}


Well what type does logo have at runtime? If it's a string, then your type declaration is wrong - why did you add this code to custom.d.ts? Not saying your way of loading svg files is wrong, but there are multiple ways to do it and you appear to have mixed them up. Without sharing more details about your build configuration, we can't tell you what exactly is wrong though.

Ah I understood what you mean. I was confusing to call svg as string or ReactComponent. Now I updated the way to calling svg from ReactComponent to string, and there are no errors. But one thing you mentioned, why am I using custum.d.ts, I think I just did it with some tips from internet without think of it deeply. If there is only this option for my custum.d.ts, would it be better to use tsconfig.json instead of it? Or are there any other option for it?

No no, using a custom.d.ts fine, I was wondering why you added these contents (that were wrong) to it. Probably the emphasis was a bit misplaced in my comment.
